# Turning of exponent label in plot and gaining exponent information

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Hello I'm looking for a way to turn off the exponent on an matplot figure. Is there an easy way to turn that off?

I'm also looking for a possibility get that exponent value. I tried already

```
ax1.yaxis.get_offset_text().get_text()
```

But that only results in a string with latex format. And I'd prefer to have a float.

In the end I'd like to have an easy possibility to position the Exponent anywhere on the plot.

I hope that concludes what I'm looking for.

Thank you for your help in advance :)

edit:
Some more code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = size)


gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1], sharey=ax1)
plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
ax1.tick_params(direction='in',labelsize=fontsize)
ax2.tick_params(direction='in',labelsize=fontsize)
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax1.set_ylabel('Intensität / willk. Einh.')
ax1.set_xlabel('Messpunkt')
ax2.set_xlabel('Messpunkt')
test = ax1.yaxis.get_offset_text().get_text()
ax1.plot([],[], linestyle = 'None',label = test + name + r' bei $p_0 =\,$'+ str(pressure[0]) + r'$\,$ mbar')
ax2.plot([],[], linestyle = 'None',label = name + r' bei $p_0 =\,$'+ str(pressure[1])+ r'$\,$ mbar')

plt.setp([ax1, ax2], visible = True)
gs.tight_layout(fig)


y0 = file(Messung['Pfad'][key[0]],Messung['Name'][key[0]])
y1 = file(Messung['Pfad'][key[1]],Messung['Name'][key[1]])
x = np.arange(0,len(y0),1)

ax1.plot(x,y1, 's', label = 'Messpunkt', markersize = 3, color = colors(T0))
ax2.plot(x,y0 , 's', label = 'Messpunkt', markersize = 3, color = colors(T0))

#format_label_string_with_exponent(ax1, axis='both')
#format_label_string_with_exponent(ax2, axis='both')
ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.3, 1, 0, 0.08), loc=1, ncol= 2, mode="expand",borderaxespad=0.5,frameon=False, fontsize = fontsize)   
ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.3, 1, 0, 0.08), loc=1, ncol= 2, mode="expand",borderaxespad=0.5,frameon=False, fontsize = fontsize)   


plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you try this - `ax1.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)` ?

Comment: yes, but that causes the ax to multiply by the exponent. So the scale is 1e-10 and I don't want to have 10 zeros before the first significant digit.

Comment: do you mind posting your code ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that helps but I edited the code that does the plotting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to turn the exponent off, in case someone is looking for that:

```
ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
```

ax is the name of the axis and its possible to turn it separately on or off x and y axis